# change options on existing geocomplete instance

Tags: jquery, instance

How would you changing the options for an instance of geocomplete's map for example change the zoomControl to true if you click the #center button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$.geocomplete()</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input id="geocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Type in an address" size="90" />
      <input id="find" type="button" value="find" />
    </form>
     <div class="map_canvas"></div>
     Call: 
    <button id="search">.geocomplete("find", "NYC")</button>
    <button id="center">.geocomplete("map").setCenter()</button>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="logger.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
          map: ".map_canvas",
          mapOptions: {
              zoom: 10,
              zoomControl: false,
        },
        });

        $("#search").click(function(){
          $("#geocomplete").geocomplete("find", "NYC");
        });

        $("#center").click(function(){
          var map = $("#geocomplete").geocomplete("map"),
            center = new google.maps.LatLng(10, 0);
            map.setCenter(center);
            map.setZoom(3);
        });
      });
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u1wcr3xo/